# How to check Face ID is disabled for my app in settings page

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, face-detection

[image]

How I can check is the Face ID is Enabled/ Disabled in settings page?
I checked in LAContext error type. It return 
Code=-6 "User has denied the use of biometry for this app."

But the device do not support biometric authentication also getting same error code. (kLAErrorTouchIDNotAvailable   -6)

Is any way to find user enabled/disabled Face ID in settings?

Answer (score 2):

first add a method for your users to enable faceid/Touch ID using local authentication. adding this method will allow users to enable and disable biometric id in settings. you can use a whatever method you'd like, button, segment controller or view and using a prompt you'll ask the users permission to enable biometric id. This code may help:

```
let context = LAContext()
var error: NSError?

if context.canEvaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, error: &error) {
    let reason = "Enable FaceID!"

    context.evaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, localizedReason: reason) {
        [unowned self] (success, authenticationError) in

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if success {
                self.unlockSecretMessage()
            } else {
                // error
            }
        }
    }
} else {
    // no biometry
}
```

Comment: Sorry. This is system settings page of iOS , Not my application.

Comment: @SharatKannan did you get any lead to check whether the toggle in the settings page of iOS is on or off?